# Tell Git: I Like It Like This

Tags: git

Sometimes I like to move a lot of files around in the OS X Finder, delete some, add some, modify some – more than 30 changes.

As things are, I need to go through and "git rm" every file I removed and "git mv" every file I moved *after the fact* when I'm not sure if I "rm'd" or "mv'd" and I don't get Bash completion because the file is gone.

When I'm done with this, I'd like to be able to say to Git: I like it like this, let's commit all these changes.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Yes! I can't believe I didn't think to look at the commit manpage (I figured it was an action needing to be taken prior to commit). Post it as an answer and I'll give you points.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `git add -A` to add the changes, then `git commit` to commit it.

Compared to `git commit -a`, this will really take the working tree as it is. It will handle new, moved, and renamed files while `git commit -a` won't. `git commit -a` ignores new files and treats moved and renamed files as deleting the files (since the files in the new location are considered new files, which are ignored).

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do

```
 git add .
```

To add all the new files (even the ones that have been moved). And

```
 git add -u .
```

For the ones that have been deleted (or moved).

Git will figure out by itself the ones that were moved. I would be surprised there is not a way to combine this into one single command, but that's what I usually do...